# mysql workbench navigator panel - move schemas up or down - change schema order

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is it possible to change the order (re-order/re-sort) of the schema listings in Navigator Panel in MySQL Workbench - to move them up or down in the Panel list?

I'm running 8.0.16 to specifically match a video course - perhaps a more recent v. might support this?

I've tried holding the classic modifier keys while both L/R click hold & drag -
nothing has worked so far.

Also searched web and rtfm without success - Thx for help.